# How to remove one character based on index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am having problem finding the proper method to accomplish this in JS. I want to iterate through each character of string (assume all lower cased) while removing `i`th character only.

So if I have string `abc`, I will iterate it three times and it will print:

```
'bc' //0th element is removed
'ac' //1st element is removed
'ab' //2nd element is removed
```

I thought I could do it with `replace`, but it did not work on string having multiple same characters.

Something like this:

```
str = 'batman';

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  var minusOneStr = str.replace(str[i], '');
  console.log(minusOneStr);
}

"atman"
"btman"
"baman"
"batan"
"btman" //need it to be batmn
"batma"
```

I realized this didn't work because `str.replace(str[i], '');` when `str[i]` is `a`, it will replace the first instance of `a`. It will never replace the second `a` in `batman`. I checked on `substring`, `splice`, `slice` method, but none suits mf purpose.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `.replace()` you'd just concatenate slices of the string before and after the current index.

```js
var str = 'batman';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var minusOneStr = str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1);
  console.log(minusOneStr);
}
```

This is because, as you noted, `.replace()`, when given a string, always replace the first instance found.